# issue with showing croped image in another div with jquery

Tags: html, jquery, cropperjs

I want to use image cropper tool for that I have use `cropper.js`.

image cropper is working fine but I want to show image after cropping in another image tag

for that I have use below code

```js
canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
        url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        var reader = new FileReader();
         reader.readAsDataURL(blob); 
         reader.onloadend = function() {
            var base64data = reader.result; 
            var croppedImageDataURL = $('.preview').cropper('getCroppedCanvas').toDataURL("image/png"); 
            
         }
    });
```

but it is not working myfor my full code I have made [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mjahav/5ysa6x4r/2/).

can anybody help me in this